# Adobe AIR app features doesn't work after obfuscation with SecureSWF 4.5

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, obfuscation

I'm creating an Android app with Adobe Air (v14) that contains a [native extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html). (ANE)
I used the SAFE pre-set of [secureSWF](http://www.kindi.com/) 4.5 to obfuscated the app but since then the features of the ANE are not longer working. (everything else is working great)
Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: there's no fix for this, ofuscate without any ane or don't ofuscate.

Comment: @BotMaster How are your sure that there is no fix for this? Isn't it possible to exlcude the ANE classes and code from the obfuscation process?

Comment: very unlikely, ane cannot be modified in any way so ofuscation can't work with them, period.